# I want to encrypt data in nodejs and decrypt it in javascript. I have tried many ways but every time i do the errors comes out malformed utf8 data

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, rsa

I have used the RSA algorithm to encrypt data using the public key and transferred the private key to the client for decryption, but it's not happening. I have tried many ways to do but it's not done I have created one repo. Link is:

[Repo Link is here](https://github.com/sudarshanmakar/EncryptDecrypt)

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

let { privateKey, publicKey } = encryption.generate_key();
console.log('Private Key:', privateKey);
console.log('Public Key:', publicKey);

const plaintext = 'This is the message to be encrypted';
console.log('Plaintext:', plaintext);

const encrypted = encryption.enc(plaintext, publicKey);
console.log('Encrypted:', encrypted);

encryption.dec(encrypted, privateKey);

res.render('final',{privateKey : privateKey,encrypted : encrypted});
```

encryption.generate_key() function

```
function generate_key() {
const keys = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 2048,
    publicKeyEncoding: { type: 'spki', format: 'pem' },
    privateKeyEncoding: { type: 'pkcs8', format: 'pem' }
});
const { privateKey, publicKey } = keys;
  
  return { privateKey, publicKey };
}

function enc(plainText, publicKey) {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(plainText, 'utf-8');
    const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(
        { key: publicKey, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING },
        buffer
    );
    return encrypted.toString('base64');
}

function dec(cipherText, privateKey) {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(cipherText, 'base64');
    const decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt(
        { key: privateKey, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING },
        buffer
    );
    return decrypted.toString('utf-8');
}
```

**Client Side Code(ejs)**

```
<script src="/jsencrypt.min.js"></script>
<script>
let privateKey = `<%= privateKey %>`;
let encrypted = `<%= encrypted %>`;
var crypt = new JSEncrypt();
crypt.setPrivateKey(privateKey);
var decrypted = crypt.decrypt(encrypted);
console.log(decrypted);
console.log(privateKey,encrypted);
</script>
```

Comment: Both codes are incompatible. The NodeJS code uses OAEP, which is not supported by JSEncrypt. Use a padding that is supported on both sides (PKCS#1 v1.5) or replace JSEncrypt.

Comment: i have tried that also but same error is coming

Comment: Well, there may be other bugs, but different paddings are incompatible. You need to fix this in any case.

Answer (score 0):

**use this method :**

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var body_parser = require("body-parser");
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

// Encryption and decryption keys
var encryptionKey = "myEncryptionKey";
var decryptionKey = "myDecryptionKey";

app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(body_parser.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    let data = "Hello world!"; // data to be encrypted
    let ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, encryptionKey).toString();
    let html = `<html>
    <body>
        <p>decryption key => : 'myDecryptionKey'</p>
        <script>
            console.log("Encrypted data: ${ciphertext}");
        </script>
        <form method="post" action="/decrypt">
            <input type="hidden" name="ciphertext" value="${ciphertext}">
            <input type="text" name="decryptionKey" placeholder="Decryption Key">
            <button type="submit">Decrypt</button>
        </form>
    </body>
  </html>`;
    res.status(200).send(html);
});

app.post("/decrypt", (req, res) => {
    let ciphertext = req.body.ciphertext;
    let decryptionKeyServer = req.body.decryptionKey;

    try {
        if (decryptionKeyServer !== decryptionKey) {
            throw new Error("Invalid decryption key");
        }
        let decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, encryptionKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        res.status(200).send(`Received ciphertext: ${ciphertext}<br>Decrypted plaintext: ${decryptedData}`);
        console.log(decryptedData)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send("Error decrypting data. " + err.message);
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on http://localhost:3000");
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Bro i have to use decrypted data at client side for some operations. And then i have to encrypt some new data at client side need to decrypt at server side. And you have decrypted data by encryption key that's not i need

Comment: @devil_sm why not just use TLS/SSL?